# E2140 expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, random-seed

```cpp
int *fillArray(int* array,const int arraySize, const int min, const int max) 
{ 
    srand(time(0));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
    { 
        array[i] = rand % (max - min + 1) - min; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You likely meant `rand()`, with a pair of parens. The compiler thinks you are trying to apply the remainder operator to a function pointer, which of course doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unrelated, but see also [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once).

Answer (score 1):

One error in your code is that `rand` is a function. To get a random number using that function you need to call it like so:

```cpp
int random = rand();
```

But in here: `array[i] = rand % (max - min + 1) - min;` your calling the modulus operator on a function pointer. This is invalid. I guess what you were looking for is this:

```cpp
array[i] = rand() % (max - min + 1) - min;
```

Another issue is that your not returning anything from the function. This will lead to undefined behavior. Make sure that your always return something (except for functions with a `void` return type).

```cpp
int *fillArray(int* array,const int arraySize, const int min, const int max) 
{ 
    srand(time(0));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
    { 
        array[i] = rand() % (max - min + 1) - min; 
    } 

    return array;    // Return the modified array.
}
```